# Getting RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD when calling the call back method on the .Net object from the native C++

Tags: c++, .net, com, win32ole

I am getting below error when I call the call back method on the .Net CLR object interface from a C++ application.

"RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread."

I get the .Net object interface as a parameter from a 3rd party .Net component, then I marshal this interface in C++ by calling "CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream" to use this .Net object in the newly created thread in my C++ application. And in the thread function, I un marshal the .Net object by calling the "CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream". Marshaling and Un Marshaling is working fine, but when I call the .Net object interface function from the thread, it return the "RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD" error.

Please let me know how can I fix this issue.

Comment: The interface pointer must be marshalled by the code that runs on the thread, not by the code that starts the thread.  It is often much easier [to use IGlobalInterfaceTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/when-to-use-the-global-interface-table).

Comment: @HansPassant : I tried IGlobalInterfaceTable marshaling also, getting the same error when I call the interface method on the un marshaled interface in the new thread.

Comment: Instead of passing callbacks you can pass COM object references (or use COM connection points https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130611-00/?p=4113 which is the conventional way to do "callback" mechanism in COM). If you don't that, you won't need to do the marshaling/unmarshaling yourself, COM will take care of it.

Comment: @SimonMourier:  Actually, I am getting the interface from the third party .Net component, then I am calling this interface methods from the new thread.

Comment: You should show some code. It's impossible to help w/o some reproducing code.